# Running Count within Date range

Tags: date, count, teradata-sql-assistant

In Teradata I am attempting to get a running total of occurances within specified a specified date range.  What I need is to find which customers had 5 or greater claims within 10 days.

The sample data:
Claim_ID    Claim_Dt    Cust_num

```
15087   1/1/2020    123000
15099   2/3/2020    123000
18473   2/8/2020    123000
18476   2/8/2020    123000
18488   2/10/2020   123000
15080   1/1/2020    133000
15082   1/1/2020    133000
18555   2/13/2020   133000
18588   2/15/2020   133000
15601   2/16/2020   133000
15711   2/18/2020   133000
15799   2/21/2020   133000
15816   2/22/2020   133000
15926   2/27/2020   133000
15988   3/1/2020    133000
```

Expected Result:

```
Cust_num   Claim_Count   Min_date   Max Date
133000           6        2/13/2020   2/22/2020
```

Here is the code as I have it so far using a LAG function:

```
select  CLAIM_DT, CUST_NUM,      
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_NUM ORDER BY CUST_NUM, CLAIM_DT) as     ROW_ID,

LAG(claim_dt,1) OVER(partition by cust_num order by claim_dt) as datediff,
claim_dt -datediff as DAYS_BETWEEN,
COUNT(claim_id) OVER(
PARTITION BY Cust_Num 
ORDER BY claim_dt
RESET WHEN DAYS_BETWEEN > 10
ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND 5 FOLLOWING 
  ) AS Claims_count, CLAIM_ID
from       (       
select  CLAIM_ID, CLAIM_DT, CUST_NUM
from    Claims_CUST_STILL_OPEN 

   ) as dt 

QUALIFY Claims_count >= 5
order by 2,1,3
```

I am able to get a simple count between the min(claim_dt) and max(claim_dt) but cannot figure out how to get a running count.

I believe I need a RESET function using UNBOUNDED PRECEDING rows, but just can't get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out which customers had 5+ claims in any 10-day span, here's one way:

```sql
SELECT 
  Cust_Num, 
  COUNT(t.claim_id) OVER(
    PARTITION BY t.Cust_Num 
    ORDER BY c.calendar_date
    ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND 5 FOLLOWING -- count # claims in 10-day window
  ) AS moving_count
FROM sys_calendar.calendar c -- Seed result set with range of days
LEFT JOIN my_table t ON c.calendar_date = t.claim_dt -- Join customer data
WHERE c.calendar_date BETWEEN <start_date> AND <end_date>
QUALIFY moving_count >= 5 -- Only get rows with 5+ claims
```

You probably can't include a `DISTINCT` in the main query, so to get a unique list of `cust_num` values, you could do an outer `SELECT DISTINCT cust_num FROM (...)` and put the query above inside the `(...)`.

Comment: This does not seem to get what I am needing exactly(though appreciated).  I need a way to have the count reset for the date range.  While this seems to get me a count of claims, it does not give me the ability to reset from each new date.  I believe the problem lies in the need for a RESET function after a 10 day period.

Comment: What do you mean by "have the count reset for the date range"?  Please add some sample expected output to your original post.

Comment: I added an expected result.  I also am working on a possible count using the LAG function and if I get it to work I'll share.

Answer (score 0):

First expand each claim row to cover the effective 10 day window (creating 10 copies of the row) and then summarize and filter the results. The outer GROUP BY is to give only one row (with largest count / latest max_dt) for each min_dt.

```
select cust_id, max(claim_ct) as claim_ct, min_dt, max(max_dt) as max_ct
FROM (
  select cust_id, count(*) as claim_ct, min(claim_dt) as min_dt, max(claim_dt) as max_dt
  FROM (
     select claim_id, claim_dt, cust_id, begin(window_pd) as window_dt
     from claims
     expand on period(claim_dt, claim_dt+10) as window_pd 
       ) expand_effective_date_range
  group by cust_id, window_dt /* running total by customer & day */ 
  having window_dt = max_dt /* only keep rows with matching claim dates */
  and Claim_ct >=5 /* and then only if count is at least 5 */
     ) summarize_and_filter
group by cust_id, min_dt;
```

Comment: This is great.  I think I was off track with the lag function and the use of a reset.